# Authentication unsuccessful while using nodemailer and office365

Tags: outlook, smtp, office365, nodemailer

I am getting the following error while trying to send email using nodemailer and office365 account:

```
Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MAXPR01CA0095.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

My nodemailer configuration is as below:

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: smtp.office365.com ,
    port: 587,
    requireTLS: true,
    tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' },
    auth: {
      user: user.email@email.com,
      pass: *****,
    },
  });
```

In Microsoft admin center, I have enabled SMPTP AUTH and also disabled two factor authentication.

Comment: I have the same issue with office365 account. Did you resolve  this Authentication unsuccessful error?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Did either of you find a good solution?